# How to find the first 5 digits of numbers in different lines that has similar first 5 digits of a txt file and print the whole lines on ubuntu

Tags: regex, ubuntu, awk, grep

I have file

```
Mds:tfy   Fg:567895435
Mds:hgf   Fg:567896553
Mds:tfy   Fg:561245746
```

But i want `Fg:56789  Mds:tfy  Mds:hgf`

I tried :

```
awk ‘{$2,$1’} /file | grep -o ‘^(fg:56789)*{f:56789}
```

but it didn’t work and not a good idea 
Thanks.

Comment: Could you please be more clear in expected sample output here? Do you need only those lines whose 1st 5 digits are similar and having count more than 1?

Comment: Yes,that’s exactly what i’m looking for

Comment: Thanks a million ,i’ll do it but  is there a command(not a program) to over come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
match($0,/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  a[val]++
  b[val]=$0
}
END{
  for(i in a){
   if(a[i]>1){
     print b[i]
   }
  }
}
'  Input_file
```